# How to delete a buffer in Vim without closing the window?

Tags: vim, vi

I usually type `:bd` to remove the buffer, however, it results in undesirable side-effect of the window being closed which I do NOT want.

Comment: this is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298910/vim-close-buffer-but-not-splitted-window

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim: Delete buffer without losing the split window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465095/vim-delete-buffer-without-losing-the-split-window)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim close buffer but not split window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298910/vim-close-buffer-but-not-split-window)

Comment: If you just want that so you can do actions without being asked to save file (like `'0`, `:e another-file`), a workaround is `98u`. Easy to type and will clear probably every modification you've done to the file, freeing you from "having" to save it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I usually use `:bn` (next buffer) followed by `:bd#` (delete alternate buffer). You could create a mapping or command for this, of course.

Answer (score 9):

```
nmap <leader>d :bprevious<CR>:bdelete #<CR>
```

Works as it should until one buffer is open in several windows. Good enough unless you want to use the bigger scripts out there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if icecrime's bufclose plugin link is based on the same thing, but the Vim Tips Wiki shows a couple of different approaches via a script. [Check them out.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Deleting_a_buffer_without_closing_the_window)

Comment: actually I think this one's better

Comment: I just noticed the see also section near the bottom of the wiki page. It mentions bufclose there, along with this comment: not useful because it doesn't work as expected (if you close a buffer that's open in several windows, those windows close). So I guess there is an issue with bufclose.

Answer (score 0):

Try [kwbdi(Keep Window on Buffer Delete)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2103) plugin. Worked well for me.