# How to delete a buffer in Vim without losing the split window?

Tags: vim

When a buffer gets deleted (via the `:bd[elete]` command), it not only deletes the buffer but also removes the split window that buffer was in.

Is there a way to delete/unload a buffer and keep the window split?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove a buffer from gvim without closing the window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403593/how-to-remove-a-buffer-from-gvim-without-closing-the-window)

Comment: [This](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2103) worked well for me.

Comment: [This one `DeleteCurBufferNotCloseWindow()` works well and is quite readable] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950143/3625404).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim close buffer but not split window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298910/vim-close-buffer-but-not-split-window)

Comment: a detailed answer is here -> https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5350/31545

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I really like [bufkill.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1147) there is a [github repo](https://github.com/qpkorr/vim-bufkill) as well

Comment: Thanks a lot, this vim behavior has bugged me a lot! btw, latest version of bufkill is at https://github.com/qpkorr/vim-bufkill

Comment: I used [bufkill](https://github.com/qpkorr/vim-bufkill) for years but found its autocmds to maintain a buffer list often threw errors. I evaluated some other plugins that accomplish a similar goal. I preferred the simplicity of [vim-bbye](https://github.com/moll/vim-bbye). The other alternative was [vim-sayonara](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-sayonara) which tries to replace all buffer/window closing commands and Do The Right Thing, but I prefer more manual control.

Answer (score 387):

`bp|bd #` will do it.

---

**Details:** The `bp` command (“buffer previous”) moves us to a different buffer in the current window (`bn` would work, too), then `bd #` (“buffer delete” “alternate file”) deletes the buffer we just moved away from. See `:help bp`, `:help bd`, and `:help alternate-file`.

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been looking for something like this which is so simple, not requiring and entire script to run it. In my VIMRC, I now have this mapped for CTRL+C: `nnoremap <C-c> :bp\|bd #<CR>`

Comment: I'm trying to remap using `nmap <silent> <leader>d :bp|bd #<CR>`, but I'm getting `E94: No matching buffer for #<CR>`.

Comment: Put a backslash in front of the `|` (e.g. `:bp\|bd`)

Comment: I knew I shouldn't have to install a plugin for this. Thanks!

Comment: `b#|bd #` will switch to the last used buffer instead of the next/previous. However, it will jump to hidden buffers if you have `set hidden`, so I made a more intelligent BD function to avoid that.

Comment: Nice and simple, though this doesn't destroy the last buffer if you're on it.

Comment: Sad that i can't hit the upvote button multiple times. Awesome solution. Thanks!

Comment: It's times like this I wish I could give more than one upvote. Not sure why it took me ~5 years to find this answer that's been here the whole time, but I'm so glad I finally found it.

Comment: @DerekMorrison that was also annoying me, if you want to close the last buffer too you can use `nmap <expr> <silent> <C-C> len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')) == 1 ? ':bd<CR>' : ':bp<CR>:bd #<CR>'` not pretty, but it works :)

Comment: Not perfect because this will close windows if the buffer is open on several of these, otherwise works very well. A perfect solution would replace the buffer in all windows where it is open, and if no buffer was left it would open a "scratch" buffer on the windows. The perfect solution would never ever close any windows.

Comment: But this keeps the file open in background. I want to close the file and not only hidding it.

Comment: @buhtz It shouldn't. See `:help bd`.

Answer (score 21):

You can add the following to your `.vimrc` to have `Bd` work as `bd` but without touching the window splits:

`command Bd bp\|bd \#`

I found this as a useful complement to what [Mud answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4468491/866439)

Comment: That's exactly what I have in my .vimrc. :)

Comment: And you can add the 3 commands for unloading, deleting and wiping out a buffer:

    command! BUN bp\|bun \#
    command! BD bp\|bd \#
    command! BW bp\|bw \#

which is equivalent to what bufkill provide but with 3 lines in vimrc instead of a 700+ lines plugin !

Comment: For me it worked only with this in .vimrc `command! Bd bp|bd #`. The command above with the `\` kept the buffer in the buffers list.

Answer (score 13):

See [deleting a buffer without closing the window](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Deleting_a_buffer_without_closing_the_window) on VIM tips wiki.

Answer (score 3):

I do something similar to @Mud, but switch to previous view buffer, `#`, instead of the previous buffer in buffer list. Here is a binding key in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>q :lclose<bar>b#<bar>bd #<CR>
```

Close Location windows, if exist, switch to the previous view buffer, and then close the last switched buffer.

Answer (score 1):

My Choice is

```
:sb # | bd #
:sb 1 | bd #
: <1. Recall Buffer> | <2. Delete Buffer>
```

Think Like that! /// <1. Recall Buffer> | <2. Delete Buffer>

```
:vert sb 2 | bd #
:vert sb <tab key~completed file(buffer)name> | bd #
```

why?! It's easy to remember 3 (+ 1) keyword!

1. sb split_buffer
2. bd delete buffer ▶ simple 2 keywords
3. # or Number of buffer
4. vert ▶ short_form of vertical (split_buffer or else)

That are easy and very useful in many other many case!

Have a nice Day! :)

Answer (score 0):

I used to use :

```
:bp<bar>sp<bar>bn<bar>bd<CR>
```

But I found certain occasions where it closed my window. On top of that the next or previous buffer might not be what you want to be displayed in the split.

Now I do this :

- switch to the buffer I want to work on
- Delete the alternate buffer

`nnoremap <leader>d :bd#<CR>`

Answer (score 0):

I actually like the behaviour of `:bd` some of the time so I use the following combination:

```
nmap <silent> <Leader>d  :enew \| bd#<Return>
nmap <silent> <Leader>w :bd<CR>
```

This allows me to use `<Leader>d` to close a buffer whilst maintaining splits and `<Leader>w` to close a buffer and split simultaneously.

1. `:enew` creates a new buffer and switches focus to it
2. `bd #` delete the last buffer that was focused