# How to close a file in a vim buffer while keeping the buffer open

Tags: vim

I open a new buffer with `:new` and then start editing a file with `:e file`, however when I quit with `:q` it closes the entire buffer, how can I exit editing a file in a buffer but keep the buffer open so I don't need to open it again to edit another file?

Comment: `:e another_file`

Comment: Aren't misusing `buffer` and `window`? In which case your question would be a close duplicate of these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465095/vim-delete-buffer-without-losing-the-split-window

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I think you may need something like:

use `:close` or `ctrl-w c` and not `:bd`

This might resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

`:ene[w]` would open a new empty buffer in the current window.

`:e filename` would load filename in that window

Comment: I'm trying to open it in a split window however

Comment: then your post is not clear. improve it so we can know what you want to achive